# Exception when split view's detail view is a TabViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios8.3

NOTE: this only seems to be a problem since 8.3.

I have a split view controller.  For easy of explanation I created a brand new master/detail project in xcode (6.3).  I changed the master view to be a tab bar.

[image]

Simply just removed the TableViewController that was part of the default project, drug in a TabBarController and added it as the master view controller relationship.

When running I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'z2L-Ml-BPJ-view-fno-cZ-fCP''

If I run in 8.1 it runs just fine.  I have no idea how to workaround this in 8.3

Comment: I am running into the exact same thing. See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614971/terminating-app-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle-with-name-7bk-jq

Comment: I have same problem!

Comment: One comment says 'In this case I solved my issue removing the storyboard segue for master and detail and adding them programmatically'  which did workaround the problem.  However 'pulling things out of storyboard' and doing it programmatically is a stupid workaround.  It should work.