# iOS 8 iPads: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

My app is crashing, but it I can't seem to locate the problem.

After startup, I call `performSegueWithIdentifier` to move the user to the right ViewController. 
**This works, except on iPads running iOS 8** (specifically it seems to happen on 8.3, 8.4 and 8.4.1 so far). Newer iPads and iPhones are no problem.

The app has a SplitViewController (which is created when calling the `performSegueWithIdentifier` mentioned earlier), so perhaps this has something to do with the problem, since it's displayed differently on iPads than on iPhones.

The exact error is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name 'I9T-iy-59z-view-exp-vQ-8nn'

Comment: is there any view controller named as `I9T-iy-59z-view-exp-vQ-8nn` you declared in your viewcontroller

Comment: I'm not sure how to search for that?

Comment: i think ur viewcontroller name is not matched please check once

Comment: Looks like you have given wrong bundle in the method parameter.

Comment: Why would this only occur on iOS8 then? And not on 9?

Comment: I would open the Storyboard file as Source Code and search for I9T-iy-59z-view-exp-vQ-8nn.

Comment: @dasdom I tried that, but it doesn't even seem to exist anywhere. I have no idea where this identifier is being determined.

Comment: I doubt he has any VC named `I9T-iy-59z-view-exp-vQ-8nn` as one would remember such a peculiar name in his project. Plus if there indeed was such a VC in use, bug should not be confined to iOS 8 only.

Comment: @KevinR did you rename any of files outside xcode? That can some times cause that issue. If you did, remove those files and add them again. Clean the project and run it again

Comment: Just did a quick search on SO. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842740/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle) lists a number of possibilities which could be the cause. See if anything is amiss.

Comment: Maybe it's due to adaptive segues. They are unavailable prior to iOS9.

Comment: @NSNoob: I can confirm this is something related to iOS8, I can reproduce the error using an 8.4 iPad simulator. the iOS9 sim works just fine. @dasdom I did more searching, the name is actually made up out of two parts. a VC with id `I3T-Sm-59z` which contains a view with id `exp-vQ-CBj` But it means it does exist at least.

Comment: I believe the encoded name is an internal creation of storyboards that they use to identify a "scene".  It's treated as an embedded NIB, similar to the content of a .xib file.

Comment: @PhillipMills Seems like a good direction to look in, but I'm not sure why it's not valid in iOS8.

Comment: @Crazyrems Are you sure? I use those everywhere, seems to work okay (on iPhones it seems to fine for example)? But I do agree I'm thinking I must do something that's not allowed/available in iOS8, the error is too vague to figure it out though :(.

Comment: @KevinR  I have no idea what's causing your error but some people seemed confused about where the string was coming from.

Comment: As a test, if you link the same segue to a different kind of view controller, do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be considered an iOS bug. I couldn't find any Open Radar or bug report, but have a look to this questions:

**1** [Terminating app: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ...' with name '7bK-jq-Zjz-view-r7i-6Z-zg0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614971/terminating-app-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle-with-name-7bk-jq)

**2** [Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle when using storyboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689235/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle-when-using-storyboarding?rq=1)

So I would suggest to insert a `UINavigationController` between the `UITabBarController` and each of the `UITableViewController` child views. as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196701/821053

Alternatively, you can get rid of the storyboard segues from *Master* & *Detail* and add them programmatically:

```
let master = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitMasterController")
let detail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitDetailController")
self.viewControllers = [master!, detail!]
```

Comment: YES! This is it! I ended up using the workaround, as it's the least invasive, specifically, I removed the master and detail segues from the storyboard and added them in the `viewDidLoad`. I'll update your answer to show what I mean :).